# How do I get the size (resolution) of all monitors in multi monitor setup

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

Is there a pure WPF way of getting information about all of the available monitor's size (resolution). I know I can use the `Screen.AllScreens` to get them but in my legacy project I cannot add new referenced (with exception to built-in WPF assemblies) and the `AllScreens` is located in located in the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` which is the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly.

Is there a way to get all of the monitors size in a pure WPF way without using WinForms assemblies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not. In WPF, you can just get the primary screen's resolution, or the virtual resolution, but not the resolution per screen.

If you want to do this, you have either to use the Win32 functions to get the screen sizes, or use the Windows Forms code (which is okay in a WPF project).

Comment: Any pointers (articles etc.) on how to achieve this with Win32 would be appreciated.